# Different SUM values on Postgres vs RedShift

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

So assume I have a list of values like so

`+---------------+
| hours_worked  |
|---------------|
| 2.08333333333 |
| 2.08333333333 |
| 2.65          |
| 4.93333333333 |
| 5.08333333333 |
| 5.08333333333 |
| 5.7           |
| 6.3           |
| 7.05          |
| 7.23333333333 |
| 7.28333333333 |
| 7.31666666667 |
| 7.63333333333 |
| 8.33333333333 |
+---------------+`

When I sum them up in Postgres, I get this

`+-------------------+
| sum               |
|-------------------|
| 76.68333333333331 |
+-------------------+`

However when I sum the exact same value in Redshift, I get this

`+---------------+
| sum           |
|---------------|
| 78.7666666667 |
+---------------+`

I manually added them and the Redshift summation is more accurate. Why does this discrepancy occurred?

Comment: Please run this command against both systems: `SELECT SUM(hours_worked), AVG(hours_worked), MIN(hours_worked ), MAX(hours_worked ), COUNT(hours_worked) FROM table` to confirm that the data is the same and that the `SUM` still varies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first I thought this was a case of [floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) arithmetics. I would then have suggested to try other datatypes in PostgreSQL, e.g., [`numeric`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html).

But I don't think this is the issue anymore. I'm pretty sure you have not given postgres the same data as redshift. In postgres, the following produces `78.76666666664`:

```
select sum(q.hours) from (
    select 2.08333333333 as hours union all
    select 2.08333333333 union all
    select 2.65 union all
    select 4.93333333333 union all
    select 5.08333333333 union all
    select 5.08333333333 union all
    select 5.7 union all
    select 6.3 union all
    select 7.05 union all
    select 7.23333333333 union all
    select 7.28333333333 union all
    select 7.31666666667 union all
    select 7.63333333333 union all
    select 8.33333333333
) as q
```

Based on the numbers it looks like you were not adding one of the first two entries `2.08333333333`. Removing on of them you get `76.68333333331`, same as your first test.

Comment: this won't test floating point arithmetics problem cases.. you need to use real tables with the datatypes to test

Comment: @RaymondNijland I did test with more datatypes. I could post them, but based on the size of the error there is no point. He simply forgot an entry.

Comment: Or cast them http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/340e0/150 seams there are indeed no  floating point arithmetics difference between `decimal`, `numeric`, `real` and `float` casted datatypes.. real datatype is rounded off it seams by the way.. "He simply forgot an entry" Yes that seams the case here.

Comment: Hi, I've looked at the data and there does not seem to be a "missing entry" ( I really hope it was)